# Sufficient conditions for a conormal vector to be regular for an orbit stratification

Tags: morse-theory, micro-local-analysis, stratifications

Let a complex reductive group $G$ act on a $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with finitely many orbits.  Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the stratification of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ according to these orbits.  Let $(x,\xi) \in T_S^{*}\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a point in the conormal to the orbit $S$.  $(x,\xi)$ is called $\mathcal{S}$-regular if it isn't in the closure of $T^{*}_{S'}\mathbb{C}^{n}$ for any orbit $S' > S$.

Are there any known sufficient conditions for $(x,\xi)$ to be $\mathcal{S}$-regular?

I have one guess which seems to be true in the simple examples I'm coming up with, but I can't find a proof or a reference.  The stabilizer $H = \mathrm{Stab}_G(x)$ acts on the fibre $(T_S^*\mathbb{C}^{n})_x$.

Conjecture: If $\mathrm{Stab}_H(x,\xi) = 1$ then $(x,\xi)$ is $\mathcal{S}$-regular

Is this known to be true, or is there an easy counterexample that I'm just missing?